# Styled components - Styles in component won't apply until I refresh. Refreshing one component breaks styles of another

Tags: reactjs, laravel, styled-components

I have a home component and a projects component. Using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/), I dynamically set the flexbox property flex-basis in projects component depending on how many projects enter props. But the style won't apply until I refresh the component. Then if I navigate back to home, the styles on that component are broken until I refresh.

It seems that refreshing one component breaks another one's styles.

I'm using Laravel with a React front-end preset.

React code:

```
<ProjectsWrapper projects={projects}>
```

Styled component code:

```
${breakpoints.tablet`
   .card {
      flex-basis: ${props => props.projects < 3 ? '50%' : '33%'};
   }
`};
```

**UPDATED TO SHOW ROUTING:**

```
return (
            <SiteWrapper>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route
                                render={({ location }) => (

                                (more code such as navigation...)

                                <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
                                            {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
                                                <Route key={path} exact path={path}>
                                                    {({ match }) => <Component data={dataObject} imagepath={imagePath} in={match != null} />}
                                                </Route>
                                            ))}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )}
                              />
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </div>
            </SiteWrapper>
)
```

The 'routes' it is mapping is a an object containing:

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', Component: HomePage },
    { path: '/about', name: 'About', Component: AboutPage },
    { path: '/projects', name: 'Projects', Component: ProjectsPage },
    { path: '/blog' , name: 'Blog', Component: BlogPage }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by refresh component?

Comment: I meant refreshing the browser whilst on that component

Comment: @xDreamCoding ^

Comment: How are you doing your routing? Also it seems you create the styled-component inline in your render every time. Try saving it to a const outside of your class and use it as jsx-tag in your render

Comment: @xDreamCoding I am creating my styled component in a const outside of my react class, further up just after the imports. And then using it with a jsx tag. And I've updated the post to show how my routing is done.

Comment: How versed are you with Chrome dev tools? I recommend getting React Dev addon and watching the styled components props while navigating, also check if your css gets applied.

Answer (score 0):

So i don't really understand how you are utilising styled components here, i don't know what `breakpoints.tablet` is but i assume a styled-component.

You'd ammend that like so:

```
const StyledCardContainer = styled(breakpoints.tablet)`
   .card {
      flex-basis: ${props => props.projects < 3 ? '50%' : '33%'};
   }
`;
```

and in the render of your ProjectsWrapper i assume:

```
<StyledCardContainer projects=${this.props.projects}>
   <div class="card">...</div>
</StyledCardContainer
```

although the CSS should be directly applied to a styled-component StyledCard for example and not via the class.

Comment: breakpoints is a javascript file with different breakpoints i.e. :

const breakpoints = {
  mobile: (...args) => css`
    @media (min-width: ${theme.breakpoints[0]}) {
      ${css(...args)};
    }
  `,
  tablet: (...args) => css`
    @media (min-width: ${theme.breakpoints[1]}) {
      ${css(...args)};
    }
  `

So the styled container should be a styled div. I'm going to refactor a little so that card is also a styled component to see if that helps. I've reverted back to using just plain css and the problem seems to go away so must be a render delay.